# MWException Global Default '' is invalid for field liberty-dark

Tags: php, mediawiki

I'm just using Mediawiki with skins but I can't access Special:Preferences
Error log

```
MWException from line 193 of /var/www/wiki/includes/preferences/DefaultPreferencesFactory.php: Global Default '' is invalid for field liberty-dark

Backtrace:

#0 /var/www/wiki/includes/preferences/DefaultPreferencesFactory.php(143): MediaWiki\Preferences\DefaultPreferencesFactory->loadPreferenceValues(User, RequestContext, array)
#1 /var/www/wiki/includes/preferences/DefaultPreferencesFactory.php(1419): MediaWiki\Preferences\DefaultPreferencesFactory->getFormDescriptor(User, RequestContext)
#2 /var/www/wiki/includes/specials/SpecialPreferences.php(129): MediaWiki\Preferences\DefaultPreferencesFactory->getForm(User, RequestContext)
#3 /var/www/wiki/includes/specials/SpecialPreferences.php(86): SpecialPreferences->getFormObject(User, RequestContext)
#4 /var/www/wiki/includes/specialpage/SpecialPage.php(565): SpecialPreferences->execute(NULL)
#5 /var/www/wiki/includes/specialpage/SpecialPageFactory.php(568): SpecialPage->run(NULL)
#6 /var/www/wiki/includes/MediaWiki.php(288): SpecialPageFactory::executePath(Title, RequestContext)
#7 /var/www/wiki/includes/MediaWiki.php(861): MediaWiki->performRequest()
#8 /var/www/wiki/includes/MediaWiki.php(524): MediaWiki->main()
#9 /var/www/wiki/index.php(42): MediaWiki->run()
#10 {main}
```

Mediawiki version:1.31.6
and skin what I using for mediawiki
https://gitlab.com/librewiki/Liberty-MW-Skin/tree/REL1_31

Comment: The error message is pretty straightforward: the default value of that preference does not match the value type defined for it. Maybe you've set something invalid in `$wgDefaultUserOptions`, otherwise it's a bug in the skin.

Comment: what should I change $wgDefaultUserOptions?

Comment: You shouldn't. You can check whether you are doing it by seeing whether it has a `liberty-dark` key.